# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Estado'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo el siguiente codigo para rellenar el select , pero al ejecutar me da este error:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that
>   has the key 'Estado

mi codigo

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Estado", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.estadosList, "- ESTADO -", new { Class = "form-control" })
```

mi controlador

```
 public List<SelectListItem> GetEstadosList()
    {
        try
        {
            List<SelectListItem> estadosList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            List<string> Estados = LaHuertaProject_dbEntities.distribuidores.Select(m => m.estado).Distinct().ToList();
            Estados = Estados.OrderBy(q => q).ToList();
            if (estadosList != null)
            {
                foreach (var estado in Estados)
                {
                    estadosList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = estado, Value = estado });
                }
            }
            return estadosList;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Que valores tiene `ViewBag.estadosList`??

Comment: Esa linea de código se ve bien, creo que el problema esta en como generar estadoList

Comment: Hola, edita la pregunta, e indica el código del Controlador donde asignas los valores al `ViewBag.estadosList`.

Comment: ya agregue el controlador , espero su ayuda